how can i use multiprocessing for web scraping in selenium python by calling one function in different driver duo to override issue
I have a sequence to do in web scraping but it took lot of time so instead of calling the single function one by one I want to pass it as different processes and if I do so I have to face conflict of multiple drivers so how can I overcome to this.
Without any conflict I want multiple process do task in there own driver with loaded prior steps in it.
Here is the code:
#importing important libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from test_sheet import connection_sheet

options = Options()
# options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) 
# options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

data = {
    'Device':'-',
    'Processor':'-',
    'Memory Capacity':'-',
    'Storage Capacity':'-',
    'Condition':'-',
    'Battery Health':'-',
    'Include Charger':'-',
    'Fully Functional':'-',
    'Price':'-'
}


def find_and_fetch():
    global data
    try:
        # Use JavaScript to hide the banner
        driver.execute_script("""
            var banner = document.querySelector('a.message-banner');
            if (banner) {
                banner.style.display = 'none';
            }""")
    except:
        print("banner disabled")

    time.sleep(1)
    if driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h5[@class='ng-binding']").text:
        text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h5[@class='ng-binding']").text
        # find processor elements and do forloop for it and call this function recursively
        if 'Processor' in text:
            processor = []
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']")
                elems = elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-keydown='selectAnswer($index, $event)']")
                for i in elems:
                    processor.append(i.get_attribute('aria-label'))
                for prces in processor:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    data['Processor']=prces
                    print("=> processor : ",prces)
                    find_and_click(prces)
                    find_and_fetch()
                    # break            
            except Exception as e :
                # print("Error While passing to processor selection!")
                print(e)
            data['Processor']='-'
            return

        # find memory capacity elements and do forloop on it and call this function recursively
        if "memory capacity" in text:
            capas = []
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']")
                elems = elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-keydown='selectAnswer($index, $event)']")
                for i in elems:
                    capas.append(i.get_attribute('aria-label'))
                for capa in capas:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    data['Memory Capacity']=capa
                    print("=> memory capacity : ",capa)
                    find_and_click(capa)
                    find_and_fetch()
                    # break     
                small_back_button()       
            except :
                print("Error While passing to memory capacity!")
            data['Memory Capacity']='-'
            return

        # find storage capacity elements and do forloop on it and call this function recursively
        if "storage capacity" in text:
            storage = []
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']")
                elems = elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-keydown='selectAnswer($index, $event)']")
                for i in elems:
                    storage.append(i.get_attribute('aria-label'))
                for store in storage:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    start_time = time.time()
                    data['Storage Capacity']=store
                    print("=> storage capacity : ",store)
                    find_and_click(store)
                    find_and_fetch()
                    # break   
                    end_time = time.time()
                    time_taken = end_time-start_time
                    print(f"The code block took {time_taken:.4f} seconds to execute.")
                    driver.quit()
                    break
                small_back_button()  
                
            except :
                print("Error While passing to storage selection!")
            data['Storage Capacity']='-'
            return

        # find condition elemetns and do forloop on it and call this function recursively
        if "condition" in text:
            conditions = []
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']")
                elems = elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-keydown='selectAnswer($index, $event)']")
                for i in elems:
                    conditions.append(i.get_attribute('aria-label'))
                for condition in conditions:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    data['Condition']=condition
                    print("=> condition : ",condition)
                    find_and_click(condition)
                    next_button()
                    find_and_fetch()
                    # break 
                small_back_button()           
            except :
                print("Error While passing to condition selection!")
            data['Condition']='-'
            return

        # find battery health elements and do forloop on it and call this function recursively
        if "battery health" in text:
            health = []
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']")
                elems = elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-keydown='selectAnswer($index, $event)']")
                for i in elems:
                    health.append(i.get_attribute('aria-label'))
                for hlth in health:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    data['Battery Health']=hlth
                    print("=> bettery health : ",hlth)
                    find_and_click(hlth)
                    find_and_fetch()
                hlth = None
                time.sleep(1)
                small_back_button()            
            except:
                print("Error While passing to battery health selection!")
            data["Battery Health"]='-'
            return
        
        # find including charger elements and do forloop on it and call this function recursively
        if "charger" in text:
            charger = []
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']")
                elems = elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-keydown='selectAnswer($index, $event)']")
                for i in elems:
                    charger.append(i.get_attribute('aria-label'))
                for crgr in charger:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    data['Include Charger'] = crgr
                    print("=> include charger : ",crgr)
                    find_and_click(crgr)
                    find_and_fetch()
                time.sleep(2)
                small_back_button()            
            except :
                print("Error While passing to including charger selection!")
            data['Include Charger']='-'
            return

        # find fully functional elements and do forloop on it and call this function recursively
        if "fully functional" in text:
            functional = []
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']")
                elems = elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-keydown='selectAnswer($index, $event)']")
                for i in elems:
                    functional.append(i.get_attribute('aria-label'))  
                time.sleep(1)
                data['Fully Functional']=functional[0]
                find_and_click(functional[0]) 
                find_and_fetch()
                small_back_button()
                
            except :
                print("Error While passing to fully functional selection!")
            data['Fully Functional']='-'
            return
    # find final price page and call fetch details function and return all details
    time.sleep(1)
    if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='your-offer']").text:
        text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='your-offer']").text
        if "Your device is valued at" in text:
            print('in the final page')
            fetch_info()
            time.sleep(1)
            large_back_button()
            return
        return
    
    # if nothing is found on page
    else:
        try:
            small_back_button()
        except:pass
        return

def find_and_click(elem):
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[@aria-label='{elem}']"))
        )
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem)
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(elem).click().perform()
    except:print("could not find any clickable element")
    return

def next_button():
    time.sleep(1)
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button success right']")
        )
    )
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", next_button)

    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(next_button).click().perform()
    return
    
def small_back_button():
    time.sleep(1)
    back = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button secondary left']")
        )
    )
    # using this page will be scrolled to the element
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", back)
    # action chain to perform moving to the element and click it
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(back).click().perform()
    return

def large_back_button():
    time.sleep(1)
    back = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.XPATH,
                "//button[@class='button secondary large left no-margin']",
            )
        )
    )
    # using this page will be scrolled to the element
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", back)
    # action chain to perform moving to the element and click it
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(back).click().perform()
    return

def fetch_info():
    global data
    time.sleep(1)
    elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH ,"//div[@class='pricing-form-final-offer']").text
    text = elem.split('\n')
    price = text[3]
    text = text[0].split(',')
    device_name = text[0].split(':')
    data['Device']=device_name[0]
    data['Price']=price
    print(data)
    connection_sheet(spreadsheet_id='1Ze7Uam6GhNGYPXvXYF3TLZPydkZQ6u5l4rmdc7CxLOU',data=data,user_sheet_name='MacInfo')
    return

def load_page(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    find_and_fetch()

load_page(url='https://www.itsworthmore.com/sell/macbook-pro-m1/macbook-pro-16-m4')

So from the memory storage I want to divide it in different driver doing their own scraping without conflict in each other.

Do you mean you want to start several web-drivers to do something separately at one web-page?

yes like that but they will be using same function

this code works but it takes 1hr and 50 min but i want to reduce time so i thought of multiprocessing so without consuming more time it will be run in multiple drivers

I wish you had posted a [mre] and it is not clear to me what logic you are trying to run in parallel. Is it that you want to run multiple calls to load_page each with a different URL in parallel? If so, do we really need to see such complicated logic for load_page?

@Deep OK I see. But I don't know what is your problem exactly by saying conflict. You can just run this code multiple times at the same time. I think it is the easiest way.

@vassiliev can i use the multiprocessing for a sequence of block which is in the sequence of my scraping task so i want to run that block of code in multiple drivers so that each sequence complete it task in same time

i tried running how it is going but its taking too much time so rather taking time in some block it runs multiple driver with different selection process

The details of the simple way for parallel process is:
(1)Limit the operation of python to one selection of the first attribute('Processor').
(2)Make python to receive the index of the selection as an argument.
(3)Prepare 3 batch files in which python is launched with every index, like this.
python py_main_mac_book.py 1
cmd/k

(4)Run all the batches by double clicking.
The following code is available for this purpose.
To automate this, you can use subprocess class of python which is included in the following code. When you run this code with the argument 0, it will work simultaneously for all the selections of 'Processor', while it will work for each selection with the argument above 0. To use this, save this as 'py_main_mac_book.py'.
It takes 19 minutes to survey 3 categories of 'Processor' in parallel.
Note parallel run of the processes, especially 3 or more, with normal view mode(non headless) may cause thermal shutdown of your PC.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#from test_sheet import connection_sheet
import sys
import os
import csv
from datetime import  datetime
import subprocess

class MacPrice:
    
    def __init__(self):

        os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
        # Select your Firefox binary.
        binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe', log_file=sys.stdout)
        # Start selenium with the configured binary.
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
        
        url='https://www.itsworthmore.com/sell/macbook-pro-m1/macbook-pro-16-m4'
        self.driver.get(url)
        
        #accept cookie
        self.cookie_accept()

        self.at_names = {
            "Processor":"Processor",
            "memory capacity":"Memory Capacity",
            "storage capacity":"Storage Capacity",
            "condition":"Condition",
            "battery health":"Battery Health",
            "charger":"Include Charger",
            "fully functional":"Fully Functional" 
            }
        self.data = {
            'Device':'-',
            'Processor':'-',
            'Memory Capacity':'-',
            'Storage Capacity':'-',
            'Condition':'-',
            'Battery Health':'-',
            'Include Charger':'-',
            'Fully Functional':'-',
            'Price':'-'
            }

    def cookie_accept(self):
        #click cookie accept button
        try:
            cookie_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH,"//button[@class='js-cookie-consent-agree cookie-consent__agree cursor-pointer button small primary']"))
                )
        except:
            pass
        else:
            cookie_button.click()

    def num_selection(self):
        '''return number of selection'''
        
        select_elms = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']/div")))
        print('\nnumber of selections: ',len(select_elms))
        return len(select_elms)
    
    def survey_start(self,index,start_time):
        
        fout = open('mac_data-{}.csv'.format(index),'w',newline ='')
        self.writer = csv.writer(fout)
        self.writer.writerow(list(self.data.keys()))

        data_key = 'Processor'
        self.selected(data_key,index-1)
        self.tree_survey()

        fout.close()
        self.driver.quit()
        print('\nProcess {}'.format(index))
        print ('started at : ', start_time )
        print ('ended at   : ', datetime.today().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ,'\n')

    def tree_survey(self):

        data_key = self.attrib_name()
        
        select_elms = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']/div")))
        
        select_num = len(select_elms)
        if select_elms[0].is_displayed():
            for i in range(select_num):
                self.select_attrib(data_key,i)
                self.tree_survey()#recursion for the next attribute
            #data clear
            self.data[data_key] = '-'
            #going back
            back= self.driver.find_elements(
                    By.XPATH,"//div[@class='animate-wrap']/button")[0]
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", back)
            time.sleep(1)
            back.click()
            
        else:#price
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                dev_elm=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='pricing-form-final-offer']/h3/strong"))
                )
                
            except:
                #case price not offered
                self.data['Price']= 'not offered'
                self.data['Device'] = '---'
                print(self.data['Price'])
                #back button
                back= self.driver.find_element(
                    By.XPATH,"//div[@class='pricing-form-final-offer']/button")

            else:
                self.data['Device'] = dev_elm.get_attribute('innerHTML')
                price_elm=self.data['Price'] = self.driver.find_element(
                    By.XPATH,"//h3[@class='your-offer']//strong")
                self.data['Price']= price_elm.get_attribute('innerHTML')
                print(self.data['Price'])
                #back button
                back= self.driver.find_elements(
                    By.XPATH,"//div[@class='offer']//button")[0]
            #output
            self.writer.writerow(list(self.data.values()))
            #back button
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior:"auto", block: "center"});', back)
            time.sleep(1)
            back.click()
            
    def select_attrib(self,data_key,i):

        select_elms = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='answers']/div")))
        self.data[data_key] = select_elms[i].text
        indicator = select_elms[i].find_element(By.XPATH,"./span[@class='selected-indicator']")
        indicator.click()
        if data_key == 'Condition':
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='animate-wrap']/button"))
                )[1].click()#forward button

    def attrib_name(self):
        prompt = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h5[@class='ng-binding']"))).text
        for key in self.at_names:
            if key in prompt:
                break
        return self.at_names[key]
    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    index = int(sys.argv[1])
    print('Process {} has started.'.format(index))
    start_time = datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    mp = MacPrice()

    if index == 0:
        processes = []
        num = mp.num_selection()
        for i in range(2,num+1):
            command = 'python py_main_mac_book.py {}'.format(i)
                    #this code itself
            process =subprocess.Popen(command.split(), 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            processes.append(process)
        mp.survey_start(1,start_time)

        print('\nReports from subprocesses follow:')
        for i, process in enumerate(processes):
            stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
            print('\nprocess ', i+2)
            if process.returncode == 0:
                print(f"succeed:\n {stdout.decode()}")
            else:
                print(f"error:\n {stdout.decode()}\n {stderr.decode()}")
        print('\nTotal Time:')
        print ('started at : ', start_time )
        print ('ended at   : ', datetime.today().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ,'\n')

    else:
        mp.survey_start(index,start_time)
        

